# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В этой деятельности любой, даже самый совершенный стандарт(,) не может гарантированно рекомендовать врачу, как поступить в той или иной ситуации.

По-моему, запятая нужна, но если выбросить эту обособленную часть из предложения, получится бессмыслица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой деятельности любой, даже самый совершенный стандарт не может гарантированно рекомендовать врачу, как поступить в той или иной ситуации.-запятая не нужна, это так называемые пояснительные определения, они отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится:Он заговорил совсем другим, серьёзным тоном.